# Excel - How to set values to a coulmn depending on values in another column?

Tags: excel

Need a value in Column B depending on values in Column A.

Example:

1221 in Cell A1 want B1 as STEEL

1245 in Cell A2 want B2 as PLASTIC

1265 in Cell A3 want B3 as COPPER

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel IF function:
https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2

For example:

```
Use IF(A1=1221, "STEEL", "")
```

In B1 cell.

This will Insert "STEEL" string in B1 in case A1 is equal to 1221 else will set it with empty string.

I hope this what you asked for.

Comment: Have you find it helpful?